# How to put distinct and count of distinct values in one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a system where students from different departments can create a group. I have the following tables:

Table `Groups`:

```
GroupID | GroupName  | GroupStatus
--------+------------+-------------
1       | Group - 01 | Incomplete
2       | Group - 02 | Complete
3       | Group - 03 | Complete
```

Table `GroupMembers`

```
GroupID | StudentID
--------+-----------
1       | 203313 
1       | 208122 
1       | 207432
2       | 212343
2       | 210434
2       | 209243
2       | 211003
```

Table `Student`:

```
Student ID | Department ID   ..
-----------+----------------
  203313   | 2
  208122   | 3
  207432   | 2
  212343   | 3
  210434   | 4
  209243   | 1
  211003   | 3
```

Table `Department`:

```
DepartmentID | ShortCode | Name
-------------+-----------+------------------------
     1       |  EE       | Electrical Engineering
     2       |  CS       | Computer Science
     3       |  ME       | Mechanical Engineering
     4       |  SE       | System Engineering
```

I want to create a view in which I can get Group Name, and Group Members Department and Count.

So output should be something like this:

```
GroupID | GroupName  | MembersDistribution
--------+------------+------------------------
  1     | Group - 01 | CS - 2, ME - 1
  2     | Group - 02 | EE - 1, ME - 2, SE - 1
```

Is a query for such a view possible?

Comment: join all tables and concat the text you want  and then GROUP BY, STRING_AGG

Comment: *"Is a query for such a view possible?"* Yes, it's possible. What about your attempt didn't work? What *were* you attempts?

Comment: What _version_ of SQL Server are you using? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `STRING_AGG()` (SQL Server 2017+) against the departments first, then joining to groups:

```
-- CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewName 
-- AS
SELECT ga.GroupID, g.GroupName, ga.MembersDistribution
  FROM
  (
   SELECT GroupID, 
    MembersDistribution = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(ShortCode, ' - ', c), ', ')
   FROM
   (
     SELECT g.GroupID, d.ShortCode, c = COUNT(*) 
     FROM dbo.GroupMembers AS g
     INNER JOIN dbo.Student AS s
     ON g.StudentID = s.StudentID
     INNER JOIN dbo.Department AS d
     ON s.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
     GROUP BY g.GroupID, d.ShortCode
    ) AS x 
    GROUP BY GroupID
  ) AS ga
  INNER JOIN dbo.Groups AS g
  ON ga.GroupID = g.GroupID;
```

Example in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1xhXGI3A).

Comment: Thank You, That worked perfectly. Only when i created the view through Designer it gave an error but when i created the view through Create View statement it worked fine. Thank You once again

Comment: @Noobie Don't use the designer, it's awful and [I've been recommending against it for 14+ years](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers).

Answer (score -5):

Yes, you can create a view that provides the desired output with the given tables. You can achieve this by using the `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` clauses in SQL. Here's the query to create the view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW GroupMembersDistribution AS
SELECT 
    g.GroupID,
    g.GroupName,
    CONCAT(d.ShortCode, ' - ', COUNT(m.StudentID)) AS MembersDistribution
FROM 
    Groups g
JOIN 
    GroupMembers m ON g.GroupID = m.GroupID
JOIN 
    Student s ON m.StudentID = s.StudentID
JOIN 
    Department d ON s.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
GROUP BY 
    g.GroupID, g.GroupName, d.ShortCode;
```

The `GroupMembersDistribution` view will have three columns: `GroupID`, `GroupName`, and `MembersDistribution`. The `CONCAT` function is used to concatenate the department's shortcode and the count of students in each group from the same department. The `JOIN` statements link the tables together based on the corresponding IDs.

Now, when you query the view, you should get the desired output:

```sql
SELECT * FROM GroupMembersDistribution;
```

Output:

```
GroupID | GroupName  | MembersDistribution
-------------------------------------------
1       | Group - 01 | CS - 2, ME - 1
2       | Group - 02 | EE - 1, ME - 2, SE - 1
```

This will give you a view with the Group ID, Group Name, and the distribution of members' departments along with their counts for each group.

Comment: Did you test this (CrapGPT) solution?

Comment: [This query does not get the right answer](https://dbfiddle.uk/sSiqoUP2?hide=8).